# How to work around WiFi bandwidth limit on big events, where there are a lot of devices connected?

Tags: lan

Assuming we want to serve something continuously on a local network to hundreds or thousands of devices, is there a solution, except for creating multiple separate networks? Or am I entirely wrong and the maximum WiFi bandwidth is not an issue?

I apologise if my question isn't clear enough, please let me know and I'll explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create separate networks, but you are going to need a whole lot of WAPs and some WLCs to facilitate roaming. Each WAP will handle about 20 or 30 users. The problem is more about the shared broadcast medium rather than the wireless bandwidth. Only one device can be using the same wireless frequency at any one time.

You will need to carefully plan the WAP placement, frequencies used, radio power, etc. That is why you get a wireless site survey before you create your installation plan. Once you have implemented this, then you can do a followup survey to tweak things.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question perfectly. I wasn't sure where to begin.

Comment: It's not strictly true that two devices can't use the same wireless frequency at the same time, thanks to CDMA

Comment: CDMA is not used on LANs, as is asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Designing WiFi networks for high density is not a matter of increasing the number of access points and controllers. If it was, we'd all be getting great WiFi service at conferences and stadiums by now.

There are physical restrictions dictated by available radio frequency bandwidth in any given physical space.

Is the event in one large exhibition hall / conference space or multiple rooms?

What is the size of each room?

How many users are expected in each room?

How many **concurrent** users must be supported in each room?

Where can Access Points be mounted? If ceiling only, how high is the ceiling?

Comment: That is what a wireless site survey tells you: WAP quantity, placement, radio power, frequencies, etc.

Comment: 100% Agreed. However, the "you're going to need a whole lot of WAPs and WLC's" statement in your answer is dangerous because that's a common misconception.

Comment: For thousands of people, you _are_ going to need a whole lots of WAPs, regardless of how carefully the office was surveyed and the WAPs were placed and configured.

Comment: Well, let's take the Ruckus R700 APs which will handle approx 200 concurrent users. They achieve this by using very advanced antenna technology combined with the latest active radio frequency management. So you can hit 2000 concurrent users with 10 of them....depending on the environment of course. That is not "a whole lot" in my world (which is event WiFi specifically).

Comment: Ten or a dozen WAPs is a whole lot of WAPs. Most of the people asking this sort of question think they can use one or two WAPs for something like this.

Comment: Also, you must consider the radios in the devices. It's not all about the radios and antennae in the WAPs. Only one device can use a frequency at any one time. You will have some not so advanced hardware and software connecting, and that affects the number of WAPs too because you cannot cram 200 desks all that close, and there will probably be some walls separating some of the users in the office.

Comment: You're right to mention radios in the device, that's the weakest link in the whole chain. That's why band steering exists which sounds fancy but is a brute force tool. The question wasn't about an office, it was about "big events" which have a very specific set of challenges. As these questions have a long life and serve as an answer for many years to come for people facing the same challenge I wanted to clarify the important details.

Comment: We have plenty of big events, with hundreds or thousands of people in office buildings. You are assuming something like a stadium, but that could be incorrect, too. The question doesn't mention the type of venue. Since "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment_," you must assume that question applies to office buildings, too.